# Setting Global Hotkeys for VLC on Windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, hotkeys

Is there a way for setting global hotkeys on VLC working on Windows XP?

I looked through the internet and found out that this feature has already been implemented. But I couldn't find exactly how to enable this feature.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/778760/74576

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you check General > Hotkeys in Preferences?

Also, restart VLC if the global hotkeys do not appear to work.

Comment: Thank you. After your message, I noticed that my VLC was old version. I have just installed the new version. Preferences > Hotkeys include settings for global hotkeys.

Comment: Im still having trouble making global hotkeys work on both vista and win8 with the latest version (2.0.5)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 it may happen that your VLC global hotkeys do not work. The solution is to start VLC in Administrator mode (right click on the program name and select 'run as administrator' from the context menu).