# Shortcut key to hide/unhide VLC media player

Tags: windows, vlc-media-player

Currently, I click on the taskbar icon of the VLC player to hide or unhide it. Is there an option in VLC media player (Windows) to set a keyboard shortcut to hide/unhide the player, preferably via global keys?

There was no such option (hide/unhide) in the Hotkeys section of the preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Go to VLC settings (preferences) and under "Hot keys", search for "Boss key", which will hide & pause any playing media: set either a hotkey (window has focus) or global hotkey (see also: https://superuser.com/a/778761 ) Then restart VLC.

Though, this really only works for quick "hide"; you'll still have to manually "unhide," using the window manager (eg, click on windows tray icon; or for linux, perhaps it'll be hidden, under notifications or paused audio applications).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no such shortcut except if you use another application that controls windows. The only shortcuts that may work when VLC is in the tray are  global hotkeys, you can define them under preferences->hotkeys.

Comment: I already use custom global keys playback. But it seems there is no option in the player to control hide/unhide via keyboard.

Comment: The current version (2.1.5) doesn't support this feature, may be they'll add it in upcoming releases.